# jenkins cli build via ssh is disconecting after 10 minutes

Tags: ssh, jenkins, keepalive

I have two jenkins instances. I want job at 1st instance to invoke job at 2nd instance, wait until it ends and perform some actions (using artifacts produced by job @ 2nd)

I've come up with this solution - using Jenkins CLI commands via SSH

```
ssh -p 2222 second-jenkins build second-job -s -v <further options>
```

But this session disconnects after 10minutes with message:

> Received disconnect from 192.168.147.102: 2: User idle has timed out
>   after 600000ms.

I [found](https://docs.oseems.com/general/application/ssh/disable-timeout) ssh client option named `ServerAliveInterval`

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -p 2222 second-jenkins build second-job -s -v <...>
```

Documentation for this option says

> ServerAliveInterval
>
> Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which **if no data has
>            been received from the server**, ssh(1) will send a message through
>            the encrypted channel to request a response from the server.  The
>            default is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent to
>            the server.  This option applies to protocol version 2 only.

This works but only when server is quiet by at least 30 seconds within every 10 minutes. Of course I can use 1 second instead 30, but it wont work for jobs with continous console output (eg. maven builds).

Is there solution which keep connection alive even for hevy console output jobs?

Comment: Why don't you just make job 2 a downstream of job 1?

Comment: @womble you mean by for example [this plugin] (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to Jenkins startup to disable the SSHD timeout:

```
-Dorg.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD.idle-timeout=0
```

See also https://blog.redaalaoui.me/blog/jenkins-cli-ssh-timeout/

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at `screen` or `tmux`. Install one of them on remote host and launch your command inside that session. `ssh` has `-t` option to allocate `tty`, so you should do something like this for `screen`:

`$ ssh -t user@host screen 'your_command'`

Comment: this is not possible since i'm connecting to jenkins built-in ssh server which provides only predefined set of commands [see here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+SSH)